# What is the difference between a Process and a Process Framework?

Tags: process

Can someone explain what are the differences between a "process" and "process framework"?

Comment: Welcome to PMSE. Please improve your question by providing some context for your question. What process or framework are you asking about? What have you already done to find the answer, and why was that insufficient for your specific case?

Comment: Going beyond what @CodeGnome already mentioned, a [Google definition](http://goo.gl/OTkKt) already makes clear the relationship between both: `A **Framework** is a model: a hypothetical description of a complex entity or **process**;`. So, what's the underlying problem you're facing related to 'Framework x Process' concepts?

Comment: I think that an answer could be a valuable reference for the PM student.  I agree that the question should have referenced the material in @TiagoCardoso's comment (google search should be a precursor to a question), but I know that PM jargon can be confusingly self-referential.  What part of the google definition posed a problem?

Comment: Exactly, @MarkC.Wallace. Once, as Code suggested, the user improves its question to the point he got stucked on (after Google research, for instance) then I'll be more than happy to upvote. For now, the downvote is on the sense that the question needs to be improved as it stands now.

Comment: thank you all, could you please take a look at the 
comment in answer

Answer (score 2):

They aren't the same. A *process framework* provides the general principles for a process. It is the *core* if you will. A process implements the process framework, but it can have other tailored, unique or company specific components. For example, RUP is a process framework (it is generic), and when your company follows the principles of RUP (it is company specific the basic ideas are the same), it is a process.

Comment: thank you @Zsolt .i think i have a misunderstanding between those concepts so i liked to correct
1)a process framework(such as RUP,MDA,..etc) considered 
as a methodology for managing and implementing the set 
of processes and each process is A series of actions 

#Does those actions need a methodology for implementing 
them as what we are noticed in implementing process?

2)the steps that lead to perform a RUP or any other 
methodology is called processes
#Does this mean that using UML in any phase of RUP 
considered as a process?

Comment: 1, No they don't. The process framework explicitly defines what to do. 2, UML is a tool. If the process says that that tool must be used, you use it. Look at this way: process framework -> how you should do it, process -> how you actually do it.